# What is the unit of width and height in circuitikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, lengths, units

```
\ctikzset{quadpoles/transformer core/inner=1,quadpoles/transformer core/height=2, quadpoles/transformer core/width=0.6}
```

What are the units of the `2` and `0.6` here?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The secret name is `\pgf@circ@Rlen `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heh. This is not a simple question; the TLDR answer is "it depends". Every length in `circuitikz` is dependent on `bipoles/length` (see manual, around page 33:)

[image]

But then there are a couple of important cases:

- some "lengths" are directly proportional to it, some others are proportional to a second length (for example, the position of the inputs in an amplifier are proportional to the height of the component, which is proportional to the basic length);
- every class of component can be scaled independently with respect to the other, so really the basic length can change among, says, `transistors` and `resistors`. You can learn more by looking for "Styling circuits..." in the manual.

Especially given the second part, it's almost useless to try to use a fixed value for the distances; in other words, `circuitikz` component will not "stay on a grid". The better way to use them is to adjust the parameters to a visually nice one (for your tastes), and then use anchors, relative coordinates and, especially, [perpendicular coordinates](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#pgf.perpendicular) to draw the circuit.

Anyway, in the case of transformers, the information available is in the manual around page 118:

[image]
[image]

so basically the two numbers are the first one (`inner`) proportional to the second one (`width`) which, in turn, and *if the scale factor is set to `1.0`*, is proportional to the basic length. Like `width`, `height` is proportional to the basic length. See:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm]% this is the default, just make it explicit
    \ctikzset{bipoles/length=1cm}% default is 1.4cm
    \ctikzset{quadpoles/transformer/.cd,
        inner=1, width=0.6, height=2}
    \draw[cyan, thin] (0,0) grid[step=2mm] (1,2)
        (0,0) node[below]{0} node[left]{0} 
        (0.6,0) node[below]{0.6} (0,2) node[left]{2};
    \draw (0,0) node[transformer, anchor=A2] (P) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]