# What is the default size of various components in circuitikz?

Tags: circuitikz

What is the default size of various components in circuitikz?

for example:

- the length of a resistor (and other bipoles)?
- if `node[npn]{Q}` is at `(0,0)`, what is the **absolute coordinate** of `Q.b`/`Q.c`/`Q.e`?
- if `node[op amp]{OA}` is at `(0,0)`, what is the **absolute coordinate** of `OA.-`/`OA.+`/`OA.out`/`OA.up`/`OA.down`?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Good question. The answer is "it depends", and it is more or less the same as here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/634952/38080.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find it if you want, but the real answer here is "you don't know". This is why there are so many anchors in `circuitikz`. For example, for the transistor, several parameters (changed with `\ctikzset`) influence the size:

1. (Public) The basic length (`bipoles/length`), see the manual [around page 33](https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/circuitikzmanualgit.pdf#18), which is the basic, arbitrary length used by all of the package components, by default 1.4 cm;
2. (Public) The *class* scale factor (`transistors/scale`), which will scale the components in its class of the factor specified (it's scoped, so you can apply it to a single transistor), see the [manual around page 38](https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/circuitikzmanualgit.pdf#21), by default `1.0`;
3. (***Private***) A bunch of internal parameters, some of them relative to the basic length, some of them relative to some other parameter, that define the exact shape¹. In the case of the `npn` shape, you can find them in the file `pgfcirctripoles.tex`:

   ```
   \ctikzset{tripoles/npn/base height/.initial=.45}
   \ctikzset{tripoles/npn/base height 2/.initial=.15}
   \ctikzset{tripoles/npn/base height/.initial=.4}
   \ctikzset{tripoles/npn/conn height/.initial=0}
   \ctikzset{tripoles/npn/height/.initial=1.1}
   \ctikzset{tripoles/npn/base width/.initial=.5}
   \ctikzset{tripoles/npn/arrow pos/.initial=.5}
   \ctikzset{tripoles/npn/bodydiode scale/.initial=.3}
   \ctikzset{tripoles/npn/bodydiode distance/.initial=.3}
   \ctikzset{tripoles/npn/bodydiode conn/.initial=.6}
   \ctikzset{tripoles/npn/curr direction/.initial=1}
   \ctikzset{tripoles/bjt/npn/curr direction/.initial=1}
   ```

   You can change them at your own risk (there are just implicit guarantees that they will not change in the future; sometimes it happens, although I always change things so that *if you don't touch internal parameters* the circuit will not change at least meaning).

Example (using https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179946/38080):

```latex
\documentclass[border=2.72mm,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\makeatletter
\def\extractcoord#1#2#3{
  \path let \p1=(#3) in \pgfextra{
    \pgfmathsetmacro#1{\x{1}/\pgf@xx}
    \pgfmathsetmacro#2{\y{1}/\pgf@yy}
    \xdef#1{#1} \xdef#2{#2}
  };
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[]
    \draw [cyan!50, ultra thin] (-1,-1) grid[step=1mm] (2,1);
    \draw [cyan, thin] (-1,-1) grid (2,1);
    \node [npn](N1) at (0,0) {Q};
    \extractcoord\nx\ny{N1.C}
    \node [above, red, font=\tiny\ttfamily] at (N1.C) {\nx,\ny};
    \ctikzset{tripoles/npn/height=0.8}% internal parameter, beware
    \node [npn](N2) at (1.5,0) {Q};
    \extractcoord\nx\ny{N2.C}
    \node [above, red, font=\tiny\ttfamily] at (N2.C) {\nx,\ny};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

***CONCLUSION:*** Use the anchors, Luke...

**Post Data:** if you use `\ctikzset{bipoles/length=1cm}` the numbers are nicer, normally:

[image]

(the 1.49998 is the same as 1.5, given the math precision/resolution of `pgfmath`).

---

¹ If I were to rebuild `circuitikz` from zero, I would do it on a grid. But when I took over the maintenance, one of my promises was to be backward compatible almost *forever*. The only non-backward compatible bug fix I did is [the first FAQ in the manual](https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/circuitikzmanualgit.pdf#ff), which you can also [follow here](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/76).